# error connection: Error: Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, xmpp

[image]

Суть проблемы такова...
Есть MySql сервер (XAMPP) проброшен в локальную сеть т.е. виден в сети порты открыты
`(1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s Microsoft SQL Server 2019 15.00.4123.00; CU5+)`
И
`1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s Microsoft SQL Server 2019 15.00.4123.00; CU5+`

Хотя через сам VSCode сам сервер доступен (скриншот)

пытаюсь подключится через VSCode, через

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");

// Создаю подключение
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "sqlserver.local", // имя удаленного сервера
  user: "SA", 
  password: "Password",
});

//подключение 
db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("error connection: " + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log("connected by id " + connect.threadId);
});
```

и получаю ошибку в таком формате

```
Server started on port 3000 error connection: Error: Packets out of
order. Got: 1 Expected: 0
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (D:\dev\sql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\sql\index.js:12:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

не поможете разобраться ?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы писать [solved], надо запостить ответ с решением в ответы.

Comment: да я тут недавно не знаю правила, написать не проблема)))

Answer (score 1):

все дело в доступе в самом phpMyadmin(xampp) в консоли прописал команду (***это именно подключению по IP***)

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED by 'ur_passwd'
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```